# iOS & Android pt sizes unequal

Tags: android, ios, fonts

Im working on an app at the mo that using pt sizes to display text. Strangely it displays on Android as I expect (with pt size adhering roughly to the standard digital pt size of 1/72") but is much smaller on iOS. Im using 10pt on android and 15pt on iOS which results is larger text on Android. What gives?! I am using differnt fonts but I tested the ttf files on android and they both render the same size side by side.

Any ideas why this is? Looking around iOS seems to have the correct pt size for text. Im an Android dev and dont really do any iOS so unsure if the platform has messed something up :p

Thanks!

EDIT: An extra layer of confusion comes from [apple 'redefining' the point dimension](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Explained/Explained.html)

EDIT: I ended up writing a [blog post](http://systemdotrun.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/whats-point-in-font-sizing.html) on this as there was more to it that I first thought :)

Comment: "point size" is almost meaningless on displays.  take your three iPad retina devices ... air, iPad and mini ...  load any app on all three.  Obviously ... **the sizes are different** !!!!  The glass is different.  Be aware that on iOS type point size goes by NON retina screens.  Your art department will typical work with normal modern retina screens, just divide the point size from Photoshop, by two.  Note that @3x apple screens are arriving this year.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: errrr - isnt the whole concept of point size is that it relates to a physical size (1/72") _regardless of the display devices size or density_ (similar to DPs on android - they are density independent)

Comment: @Dori: No. At least, not anymore. Point size is essentially a scale factor. There is no guarantee that 12 point on one device will by physically identical to 12 point on another device. It should occupy the same number of *pixels*, but the problem is the pixels are different physical sizes (and sometimes, even shapes!) on different devices.

Comment: @djangodude Im now aware that apple have their own definition of `point`. Where are you getting the idea that _"It should occupy the same number of pixels"_ from, as this goes against everything i have seen about `pt`s. Understand pixels are differnt shapes and density on different devices, but AFAIK thats the whole point of density independent measurements like `pt`, `dp` and even `mm` on some systems - which is to abstract away the devices / display particulars. Apart from on iOS which is confusing things but using the same terminology for a dimension with different properties. Thx :)

Comment: Ignoring the iOS issue for now: the use of 'points' came from pre-electronic typography (where it *was* an exact physical measurement). The use of points in electronic/digital displays was adopted because at the time, the actual physical size of device pixels was *roughly* one point. Thus it made an easy transition from the physical print world: 1 point == 1 pixel and the actual physical size was pretty close; enough for "WYSIWYG". But if you had a device that happened to have smaller physical pixels, 12 point on one device would be the same number of *pixels*, but not the same physical size.

Comment: Apple's "redefinition" of a point is to be able to accommodate high-res (Retina) and standard-res without a change to application code. Retina pixels are *roughly* (but not exactly) 1/2 the size of non-Retina devices (where even amongst those devices, the actual physical pixel size varies). The pixels are *so* small that they could not continue using the standard resolution definition of one point being one pixel. Thus, on Retina devices, one point is *2* pixels. Since the physical pixel size is roughly half of that on normal devices, this gets you pretty close to the same physical size.

Comment: Bottom line for your case: if you want the _exact_ same *physical* size, you're out of luck: it is simply not possible when the physical pixel sizes differ. At best, you can get close, *if* you know the physical pixel sizes. You could express those as a ratio to points (1/72") and apply that scaling factor to your point size on different devices. But that is really the problem: there's not a good way to reliably know the physical size of the pixels you're rendering to.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a blog post on this. Seems like Android gives you a bit more control over this stuff http://systemdotrun.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/whats-point-in-font-sizing.html